# Are there advantages to using BigQuery as a data source of ndarrays for Dataproc if calculating kmeans clustering using python

Tags: google-bigquery, pyspark, k-means, google-cloud-dataproc

I understand from the documentation for Dataproc its possible to read data from BigQuery using pyspark but is there an advantage when running kmeans clustering on ndarrays with a shape (xxxxxxx,) over say reading a file representation from CloudStorage instead

Answer (score 1):

If you are not intending to do any other manipulation of your data in BigQuery, then you absolutely wouldn't gain anything from storing your data in BigQuery for this use case.

Per https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/bigquery-connector,

> The BigQuery connector for Hadoop downloads data into your Google
>   Cloud Storage bucket before running a Hadoop job.

In other words, the connector doesn't do predicate push-down or otherwise leverage BigQuery for computation; this connector is just a convenience method to provide access to data that you're already storing or generating in BigQuery.

Comment: Would you expect to see a performance improvement or otherwise have a more scalable solution by including BigQuery as the data source though?

Comment: No; actually the opposite.  Your data would need to be exported from BigQuery to Google Cloud Storage in order to be accessible to Dataproc, so you'd be adding latency to your query.

Comment: looks like it bq does support filter pushdown? https://medium.com/geekculture/predicate-pushdown-for-apache-spark-with-google-bigquery-2ad4f9e81e6